# I cant login or register to my app

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my app. When I want to login or register the `ProgressDialog` will be show and never cancel. During the app is running it must cancel and "ok" Message must be shown.

Here is my code:

**Main**

```
package com.example.server;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

private ImageView login,register;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    login=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_login);
    register=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_register);


    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent lo=new Intent(Main.this,login.class);
            startActivity(lo);

        }
    });



    register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent lo=new Intent(Main.this,register.class);
            startActivity(lo);              

        }
    });




}






}
```

**login**

```
package com.example.server;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class login extends Activity{



private ImageView login,exit;
private EditText usertext,passtext;

public static String res="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);



    login=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login_login);
    exit=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login_exit);

    usertext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.usertext);
    passtext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.passtext);


    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            login(usertext.getText().toString(),passtext.getText().toString());

        }
    });




    exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            finish();


        }
    });




}

public void login(String user,String pass){

    new loginserver("http://ujo.ir/login,php",user,pass).execute();

    final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(login.this);
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
    pd.show();

    final Timer tm=new Timer();
    tm.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if(!res.equals("")){
                pd.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                res="";
                tm.cancel();
            }
            }
        });

        }
    }, 1, 1000);


}






}
```

**register**

```
package com.example.server;

import java.io.ObjectOutputStream.PutField;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import com.example.server.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class register extends Activity{

public static String res="";
private ImageView register,exit;
private EditText name,family,user,pass,email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);


    name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.re_name);
    family=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.re_family);
    user=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.re_user);
    pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.re_pass);
    email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.re_email);


    register=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.re_register);
    exit=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.re_exit);




    exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            finish();

        }
    });



    register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {


        register1(name.getText().toString(),family.getText().toString(),user.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString());

        }
    });


}

public void register1(String name,String family,String user,String pass,String email){

    new registerserver("http://ujo.ir/register.php", name, family, user, pass, email).execute();

    final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(register.this);
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
    pd.show();

    final Timer tm=new Timer();
    tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

            if(!res.equals("")){    
            pd.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            res="";
            tm.cancel();

            }
        }
    });


        }
    }, 1, 1000);


}



}
```

**registerserver**

```
package com.example.server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;



public class registerserver extends AsyncTask{

private String Link="";

private String Name="";
private String Family="";

private String User="";
private String Pass="";

private String Email="";


public registerserver(String link,String name,String family,String user,String pass,String email){

    Link=link;
    Name=name;
    Family=family;
    User=user;
    Pass=pass;
    Email=email;
}



@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {


    try{

        String data=URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Name,"UTF8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("family","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Family,"UTF8");

        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(User,"UTF8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Pass,"UTF8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Email,"UTF8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("status","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("a","UTF8");

        URL mylink=new URL(Link);
        URLConnection connect=mylink.openConnection();

        connect.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr=new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();


        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

        String line=null;

        while((line=reader.readLine()) !=null){

            sb.append(line);

        }

        register.res=sb.toString();




    }catch(Exception e){



    }



    return "";
}

}
```

Comment: I didnt get your question. You can cancel the ProgressDialog by pressing the back key. or dnt you want to cancel even when back key is pressed ?

Comment: No i don't want to cancel ProgressDialog
i want to login to my app with this user and pass
user=mili
pass=123
but i can't login in it
u can download source of my app..
Download: http://ujo.ir/server.zip
can anybody please help me?

Comment: What is the purpose of timer here ?  
From login.java , you are calling an async task loginserver . 
The value returned by doInBackground() is sent to onPostExecute() . 
So you should call onPostExecute() in your login.java and assign the value to the String "res"
rather than assigning the value to the static variable in your asyn task. 
The below two links explain how to use AsyncTask :
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: No my teacher do it without onPostExecute() and it worked...

i ask him for answer but till now he didn't tell the answer

can u import my app to ur eclipse and test it without onPostExecute()?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are two error.

1. In loginserver.java , the variable assignment is reversed in constructor

Your code is

```
   public loginserver(String link,String user,String pass){

        link=Link;
        user=User;
        pass=Pass;

    }
```

It should be

```
    public loginserver(String link, String user, String pass) {

    Link = link;
    User = user;
    Pass = pass;

    }
```

2. It is a typo in your login.java

In your code

```
    new loginserver("http://ujo.ir/login,php",user,pass).execute();
```

Its login.php not login,php

I changed these two and logged in using the user id and password . 
I got the toast message "ok"

If you are making a http connection , it would be good to use 
HttpURLConnection instead of URLconnection as it provides extra API to deal with http connections. I have attached the code for loginserver.java

```
     protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

        try {

            String data=URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(User,"UTF8");
            data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Pass,"UTF8");
            Log.i("loginserver","loginserver is called"+data);//helped to find the error 1

            URL mylink=new URL(Link);
            HttpURLConnection connect=(HttpURLConnection) mylink.openConnection();
            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            connect.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            OutputStreamWriter wr=new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
            Log.i("loginserver","after flush"+connect.getResponseCode());//helped to find the error 2
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line=null;
            while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
                Log.i("loginserver","we enter while");
            sb.append(line);    

            }

            login.res=sb.toString();
            Log.i("loginserver","value is" + login.res);


        } catch (Exception e) {


        }


        return "";
    }
```